# Apache commons no static method

Tags: java, android, apache-commons

There is a crash on Xiaomi Mi5 6.0.1

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method equalsAny(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;[Ljava/lang/CharSequence  Z 
>   in class Lorg/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)

We are using

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
```

It works well on other 6.0.1 devices, also my Xiaomi Mi3 works well. I don't know, what i supposed to do to solve this crash.

**UPD#1**
I guess, I have found the reason of crash. I have read error more attentively and this part says

> appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex

that there is a class with same signature in framework. And probably my import is replaced with framework's one. But I still have no solution.

Comment: Can check there is no other jar that has this class?.me be it is pooling that.

Comment: @Yohannes i have already run `gradlew dependencies`, apache-commons are imported only in root project. Also i used apk analyzer and found StringUtils class in dex files and it contains this method. I searched by class name via ctrl+n, and there is only a single result.

Comment: @Ufkoku were you able to resolve this issue? I am running into it with the same device and OS too

Comment: @JamesBond the only solution I have found was to replace the usage of this method.